# django view - user passes test multiple conditions?

Tags: django

Im using the below to make sure a user has a custom permission before allowing them to run the view. however I would like to add multiple conditions, i.e. a user has_perm sites.can_view_mgmt or sites.can_view_finanical

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.has_perm('sites.can_view_mgmt'))
```

is it possible to have an or in user passes test?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## OR-logic

If at least *one* of the conditions has to be satisfied, you can use an `or` in the lambda expression:

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.has_perm('sites.can_view_mgmt') or u.has_perm('sites.can_view_mgmt'))
def some_view(request):
    # ...
    pass
```

If the list is large, you can use the `any(..)` function:

```
need_one_of = ['sites.can_view_mgmt', 'sites.can_view_mgmt']

@user_passes_test(lambda u: any(map(u.has_perm, need_one_of)))
def some_view(request):
    # ...
    pass
```

## AND-logic

If *all* conditions have to be satisfied, you can use an `and` instead of an `or`. Django however has a [**`User.has_perms`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perms) function as well that checks if *all* permissions hold, so:

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.has_perms(['sites.can_view_mgmt', 'sites.can_view_mgmt']))
def some_view(request):
    # ...
    pass
```

Or we can use the `all(..)` function:

```
need_all_of = ['sites.can_view_mgmt', 'sites.can_view_mgmt']

@user_passes_test(lambda u: all(map(u.has_perm, need_all_of)))
def some_view(request):
    # ...
    pass
```

Comment: This is straight forward and easily understood. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is write a function to pass to `@user_passes_test` that includes all your checks.

something like this:

```
def user_test(user):
    try: 
        assert user.has_perm
        assert user.next_test
    except AssertionError:
        return False
    return True
```

and so on until you find a test that breaks it or you don't, and the user passes. Then, you just pass `user_test` to the decorator and you're good to go.

`@user_passes_test(user_test)`

Comment: But wouldn't that raise an error in `user_test`. Given I understand it correctly, the test should return `True` or `False`.

Comment: the point is that it should raise an error. sorry my pseudocode isn't perfect, really you should be asserting and catching exceptions.  If you catch an exception, return `False`, otherwise return `True`

Answer (score 0):

For proper way and other custom permission checking, do as @rchurch4 told above.
but modify is as:

```
def user_test(user):
if user.has_perm: 
    return True
else:
    redirect(<login_page>) OR
    redirect(<custom_error_page>)
```

Also I used similar logic if you want to more like:

```
def management_required(function=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, 
login_url='home:home'):

actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
    lambda u: u.user_role == 2,
    login_url=login_url,
    redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name
)
if function:
    return actual_decorator(function)
return actual_decorator
```

And than just put it on view:

```
@manangement_required
def view_home(request):
  pass
```